# Xamarin Forms Change Tab Title in Tabbed Page

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, mobile, translation

I am developing an app in Xamarin forms that supports English and Arabic languages. I implemented the translation logic and it works fine, but I faced a case where I have to translate the tabs titles in a tabbed page but did not know-how. **So the question is how can I access the title of the tabs on a tabbed page from the .cs file?** Thanks in advance.

Comment: tabs get their titles from the title property of each page

Comment: @Jason I tried adding this.Title = {translated text} in the page but it did not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your TabbedPage consists of several NavigationPages. You need to set the Title of the NavigationPage. Here is an example with xaml:

TabbedPage:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:yourApp;assembly=yourApp"
        x:Class="yourApp.MainPage">

    <NavigationPage Title="Bottom Title (Page 1)">
        <x:Arguments>
            <local:Page1/>
        </x:Arguments>
    </NavigationPage>

    <NavigationPage Title="Bottom Title (Page 2)">
        <x:Arguments>
            <local:Page2/>
        </x:Arguments>
    </NavigationPage>

</TabbedPage>
```

And one NavigationPage:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ContentPage 
       Title="Top Title (Page 1)" 
       xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
       xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
       x:Class="yourApp.Page1">

</ContentPage>
```

For more information take a look at the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/tabbed-page)

Edit: Here an example for C#:

TabbedPage:

```
public class MainPage : TabbedPage
{
    public MainPage ()
    {
        var page1 = new NavigationPage (new Page1());
        page1.Title = "Bottom Title (Page1)";
        var page2 = new NavigationPage (new Page2());
        page2.Title = "Bottom Title (Page2)";

        Children.Add (page1);
        Children.Add (page2);
     }
}
```

one NavigationPage:

```
public class Page1 : ContentPage
{
    public Page1()
    {
        Title = "Top Title (Page1)";
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry my mistake I did not mention that I want to access it programmatically not from .xaml

Comment: so instead of adding them from xaml I have to add them programatically and set the title of that page to what I want, right? Thank you also!

Comment: Yes that’s right. If you need further information, you can look at the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/tabbed-page) or ask again